# Run Destroy-Time Provisioner before local_file is deleted

Tags: terraform

I have a Terraform script which creates a `config.json` file and then runs a command that uses that `config.json`:

```
resource "local_file" "config" {
  # Output vars to config
  filename = "config.json"
  content  = "..."

  # Deploy using config
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "deploy"
  }
}
```

This all works great, but when I run `terraform destroy` I'd like to run a different command - I tried to do this with a destroy-time provisioner in a `null_resource` by adding the following:

```
resource "null_resource" "test" {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
        when        = "destroy"
        command     = "delete"
    }
}
```

The script is run, but it runs **after** the config file is deleted - it errors, because it needs that config file to exist for it to know what to delete.

How would I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the destroy time provisioner into the original resource, and it worked great:

```
resource "local_file" "config" {
  # Output vars to config
  filename = "config.json"
  content  = "..."

  # Deploy using config
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "deploy"
  }

  # Delete on_destroy
  provisioner "local-exec" {
        when        = "destroy"
        command     = "delete"
  }
}
```